# writing in specific position in a text file using ruby

Tags: ruby, file, rubygems, faker

I want to insert data in specific positions in a text file, like in line 1 starting from position 10, how can I do it using ruby?
I also want to pass fake data into this file using fakker gem or in any other way possible. Like sending phone number, name, SSN etc.

Comment: It's possible to overwrite text in a text file, but not to insert text without shifting other text in the file. The standard way is to create a new file with the inserted text. You can then optionally delete the original file and rename the new file to the name of the original file. Is there some reason you don't want to do the latter?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Your question is off-topic: You're asking us to write a tutorial explaining the issues, and how to write it, however, that information already exists in multiple places on SO. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" is important.

Comment: I did try to find it on 'SO' but all the questions spoke about writing in a file or replacing data in a file, but I dint find anything which talked about entering data in a specific position. Hence posted this.

Comment: I know that we can read strings in a file for eg. File.open(file_path, 'r') do |f|
      f.readlines.each do |row|
        x = row[4, 2].strip In the similar way I want to write strings in line 4 with two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample script that takes two arguments and writes a modified copy of the first file's contents to the second file:

```
require 'faker'

input  = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r')

lines = input.readlines
lines[0].gsub!(/^(.{0,10})/, '\1' + Faker::Base.numerify('###').to_s)

output = File.open(ARGV[1], 'w')
lines.each do |line|
  output.write(line)
end
```

If you have an input file that looks like:

```
12345678901234567890
          ^^^ fake data
```

the output might look like:

```
12345678909451234567890
          ^^^ fake data
```

Since I opened the output file after reading the input file, you can pass the same file name as both the first and the second argument. That isn't exactly inserting the string into the file, but it's as close as you'll get.

The key line is:

```
lines[0].gsub!(/^(.{0,10})/, '\1' + Faker::Base.numerify('###').to_s)
```

It takes the fist line and substitutes in place a random 3-digit integer. If there are fewer than 10 characters in the first line, it'll append the random data to the end of the line. If you'd prefer to not substitute, you might want to remove the beginning of the range in the regex:

```
/^(.{10})/
```

Or maybe do something else `if lines[0].length < 10`.

Comment: @Ruby_Learner: No problem! Please also see [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!